# C# Combo Box in Form Not Adding Items

Tags: c#, combobox

I'll preface this with I'm new to C# and trying to understand combo boxes. This is code from Form1 - just a new form with a combo box in it called cbTimeZone and a button to show the selected TZ and exit. The problem is, when I go to run it, the combo box doesn't populate, even tho I am specifying it in the Form1_load method. The names are all right, so that's not it. What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbTimeZone.Items.Add("(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London");
            cbTimeZone.Items.Add("(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West");
            cbTimeZone.Items.Add("(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa");
            cbTimeZone.Items.Add("(GMT-10:00) Hawaii");
            cbTimeZone.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }

        private string GetTimeZone(string selectedTZ)
        {
            if (selectedTZ == "(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London") { return "GMT Standard Time"; }
            if (selectedTZ == "(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West") { return "Dateline Standard Time"; }
            if (selectedTZ == "(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa") { return "Samoa Standard Time"; }
            if (selectedTZ == "(GMT-10:00) Hawaii") { return "Hawaiian Standard Time"; }
            else
            {
                return "US Eastern Standard Time";
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Timezone: " + GetTimeZone(cbTimeZone.SelectedItem.ToString())); 
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void cbTimeZone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the load event wired up?  Use the OnLoad override instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what would be wrong as I tried this exact thing on my End and it worked just the way you want it to work. can you say if this is still a problem for you?

[image: I quickly added this on an application i was working on.]

Answer (score 0):

I've tested, Your code is working. There can be two issue, either your Form Load event is not wired up Or VS is not creating new exe. Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I added

```
this.Load += Form1_Load;
```

and that seemed to fix my issue.

Not sue why I needed that, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Because that subscribes the event, otherwise, nothing is calling that load code.

Comment: In general, if you are using Visual Studio, let it manage the events and event wire-up.  For example, to wire-up FormLoad, double-click on the form.  The `this.Load += Form1_Load;` code will go into your `*.designer.cs` file, and VS will bring up the newly created Form_Load method.  Let VS do it's job - learn how to use it.